# Implementing regex in comma separated numbers

Tags: regex

i am a total noob into regex expressions.

i have something like this coming from a serial input.

```
6,0,0,0,0,0,259,2508,20,169
55,0,0,0,61,0,259,2508,20,169
91,0,0,0,60,0,259,2508,20,169
126,0,0,0,60,0,259,2508,20,169
162,0,0,0,60,0,259,2508,20,169
198,0,0,0,61,0,259,2508,20,169
```

i want to match each line to see if there is 10 numbers separated by a comma each, i believe the end of the line is checked by \r\nA but i don't really understand much of regex, if someone know the answer can i have some explanation on what does it mean?
Thanks!

Comment: For future knowledge, this was for labview 2011, so apparently it doesn't support this kind of regex abreviations, had to do it long version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+(,\d+){9}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR8yE8/1)

Comment: What exactly does that mean? i have a serial input and i tried it but it wont get it, i bet its because i need to look for the character return or end of line, this was the regex that was used before in this application, not sure what it looks for     \r\n[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\r\nA

Comment: Check the working demo. You need to use `multiline` flag as well. Which tool are you using for this regex?

Comment: i am using it in labview, which wont get me the results :/

Comment: i have to add at the begining and last to search for \r\n

Comment: ok then try this regex: `\d+(?:,\d+){9}[\r\n]*` [or see this demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR8yE8/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, for some reason i haven't been able to get a value, as you can see the probe has the data in the format i told but the expresion wont be matched. https://imageshack.com/i/exanLqEUp

Comment: Difficult to understand your input data from that image. Better to take my update demo http://regex101.com/r/hR8yE8/2 and populate the input data which is not working for you and then show me updated link.

Comment: I placed the output of the serial into a txt to see it in notepad++ i get what i should. https://imageshack.com/i/eyaKjO8Kp

Comment: it's wierd, since i can see that it does work on your demo, but for some reason it wont work on my app :(

Comment: Sorry, I can only make it work if you provide me a demo link with relevant data on regex101.com

Comment: im trying to do \d alone by itself and it wont do anything, maybe this wont support that regex, i used [0-9] and i do start mathcing but digit by digit

Comment: I got it working with what might be a horrible regex but it works,             `[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\r\n` the only thing is that in the 6th value it might be a negative value, so it will have a - before the number, but it also might not have it

Answer (score 1):

try this. It will match lines that have more than 10 digits long.

```
(\d{1,},?){10,}+
```

Check the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/xK3jG0/2).

Comment: it will still grab commas after it